# Troubles changing value of CurrentBrowser variable in BrowserWindow in Coded UI Tests

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have installed VS 2017(entrprise) in my Windows server 2012 R2 and I trying to launch IE(11) browser in my coded UI test. But every time I run the code mentioned below I see that BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser value does not get changed from 'IE'(default value) to 'iexplore'(the value I want to assign).
It does to throw any exception or error but it also does not change the value of BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser.

```
            Uri gotourl = new Uri(uri);

            BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "iexplore";

            BrowserWindow currentBrowserWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch();

            currentBrowserWindow.NavigateToUrl(gotourl);
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was it was not able to find the correct version of the playback assembly class (which is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting Version 14.0.0.0). I added the correct version and also I added Playback.Initialize(); before the code and it worked.

```
    Playback.Initialize();

    Uri gotourl = new Uri(uri);

    BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "iexplore";

    BrowserWindow currentBrowserWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch();

    currentBrowserWindow.NavigateToUrl(gotourl);
```